# Loading data from database with php and pure ajax in a textbox

Tags: php, ajax

i have one dropdown list which has data for "subjects" loaded from database. when i clicked on one subject what it should do is load related "subject_id" value inside textbox which is just below dropdown list option.  i dont know how to bring value from getbook.php and show in book_ID input text.

```
show_bookid(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("bookid").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        strong text
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXOjbject("Microsoft.XMLHttpRequest");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("bookid").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getbook.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**getbook.php**

```
<?php
<?php
$b = $_GET['q'];
include('includes/security.php');
include('includes/dbconnect.php');
$database = new MySQLDatabase();

$sql = "select * from tbl_bkcat where book_id='" . $b . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
?>
```

below is the File where i need to bring value

```
<form name="bookadd" action="" class="jNice" method="post">
    <p>
        <label>Subject</label>
        <select name="subject" onChange="show_bookid(this.value);">
            <?php while($sel_rows=mysql_fetch_array($subresult)) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $sel_rows['book_id'];?>">
                <?php echo $sel_rows[ 'subject']?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Book_Id</label>
        <input type="text" id="bookid" class="text-small" />//where i need to load subject id</p>
```

Comment: where is the subject_id coming from? I can see only book_id listed in the code. For subject_id do you need to query again? Please give more details.

Comment: Doesn't <?php <?php throw any error in getbook.php ? Because it should... PS, take care of that MySQL injection prone code available there.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia thanks for your sugggestion broda

Comment: @ashoka I have already loaded subject(in select option) as well book_id(or call subject_id) using php. what I want is when any subject(which is loaded in select option field) is selected(onchange event) ajax is used to carry that event and bring required book_id in <input type="text" id="bookid" class="text-small"/> but how to do it.

Comment: Your code here seems to have a few issues, pointed out by other users : 1. '<?php<?php' 2. no echo in getbook.php 3. where and how do you select books by subject? Please fix these problems. Also try going to getbook.php with your browser and see what it prints out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was done at ajax part  **document.getElementById("bookid").innerHTML** and must be replaced with **document.getElementById().value** since I had to put data to  **Html Element** that cotain value i.e Textbox(as textbox contain value attribute).

**InnerHTML**  is used to manipulate the **html elements** that does not contain **value**,
 ** div,h1, ** etc. for details see below link.

http://www.verious.com/qa/what-39-s-the-difference-between-document-get-element-by-id-quot-test-quot-value-and-document-get-element-by-id-quot-tes/

**ajax code**

```
  function show_bookid(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if(str.length==0)
    {
        document.getElementById("bookid").value="";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXOjbject("Microsoft.XMLHttpRequest"); 
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("bookid").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getbook.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**getbook.php**

```
<?php
$b=$_GET['q'];
include('includes/security.php');
 include('includes/dbconnect.php'); 
$database=new MySQLDatabase();

$sql="select * from tbl_bkcat where book_id='".$b."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['Book_id'];
?>
```

addbook.php

```
            <form name="bookadd" action="" class="jNice" method="post">
            <fieldset>

                <p><label>Subject</label>
                 <select name="subject" onChange="show_bookid(this.value);">

                 <?php

                    while($sel_rows=mysql_fetch_array($subresult))
                    {
                 ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $sel_rows['book_id'];?>">
                    <?php echo $sel_rows['subject']?>
                    </option> 
                    <?php 
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
                </p>

                <p>
                <label >Book ID</label>                 
               <input type="text" id="bookid" name="book"/>
                </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `subject_id` is not displaying because you have not printed your `book_id` after fetching results from database in getbook.php

After this `$result=mysql_query($sql);`

Write `echo $result['your_book_id_field_name'];`

Comment: you don't fetch data base data with ajax, you fetch it with PHP

Comment: @Onheiron thanks! I've done good search on this topic and got good knowledge.