# Show values in the textboxes

Tags: php, html

I have a table callled tb_app with fields 'id','name','aic','batchcode'

example: field values   '1','james','0001','1'

If type james in the textbox(name) corresponding values for other fields(aic,batchcode) should be displayed in textboxes. Is this possible? can anyone help me...I'm a php beginner ...Please!

Form code:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="names" id="query" />
 <input type="text" name="aic" />
 <input type="text" name="batchcode" />
 <input type="submit" name="show" />
 </form>
```

Comment: You can do it with ajax on `names` textbox's blur event.

Comment: try this link it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480773/loading-data-from-database-with-php-and-pure-ajax-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Jquery ajax Try in this way by using your exact field names it might help you

Your jquery script should be something like this

```
 function getvalues()
    {

         var selname = $("input[name='names']:text"").val(); 

            $.ajax({ url: "getuserdata.php",
                data: {"selname":selname},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(output) {
                                $("#aic").val(output);
                                $("#batchcode").val(output);

                }

            });
    }
```

and your Html code

```
  <input type="text" name="names" id="query" onblur="getvalues()"/>
  <input type="text" name="aic" id="aic"/>
  <input type="text" name="batchcode" id="batchcode" />
```

The getuserdata.php

```
<?php 

include("database connection file here");
$selname = $_POST['selname'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE youruser_id = $selname";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo $rows['aic']; 
echo $rows['batchcode'];
?>
```

Comment: youruserid is the field name id?

Comment: since you are posting the name in textbox this should be your filed_name in the table

Comment: y it doesnt show the aic and batchode in their corresponding textboxes when i input a name?

Comment: the selname in the jquery script what is this? my table field name? or the textbox input name?

Comment: Im confused in selname:selname in the script.

Comment: This is just a variable that holds the value of name entered in the textbox

Comment: can you please explain to me the whole script cause I'm confuse...I'm still new to ajax

Comment: after entering name in the textbox and when that field loses focus the name is captured by jquery and that name is sent as a post request to the getuserdata.php in which we are wirting a sql query to get the corresponding values of that particular name and passing the response back to your php file and the result is being put back in to the exact box of the html form based on the field id

Comment: I got an error inside the aic and batchcode texboxes...it says.

Comment: <br /><b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\getuserdata.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: i figured it out the error...now i got this error inside the textbox...Unknown column 'james' in 'where clause'.